# Добавление метода в объект класса Java

Tags: java, методы

Возможно ли в Java добавление экземпляру класса метода непрописанного в классе?

Например:
Есть класс **HumanHero** и его экземпляр **Hercules**.
Изначально наш герой не может летать, но вот, случается чудо и, по стечению обстоятельств и личному благоволению Зевса, наш герой отращивает себе крылья и получает данную способность.

Вопрос:
Есть ли возможность добавить  экземпляру класса **HumanHero** метод ***fLy()***, если при создании класса, данный метод там не был прописан?

Comment: Вообще нельзя, но если заниматься извращением, то есть Project Lombok. Посмотрите эту аннотацию -> https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod

Comment: Спасибо! Цель была как раз не заниматься извращениями, а узнать о теоретической возможности/невозможности  данного действия. Аннотацию прочту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не совсем верно представляете себе принципы ООП, согласно им свойства/методы имеет не экземпляр класса, а класс. Если вы хотите, чтобы один класс имел другие свойства/методы относительно другого класса это решается на уровне иерархии классов. В вашем примере это бы выглядело так:

```
abstract class HumanHero {
   public abstract void fly();
}

class Prometheus extends HumanHero {
   public void fly() { System.out.println("No, I can't fly"); }
}

class Hercules extends HumanHero {
   public void fly() { System.out.println("Flying is awesome!"); }
}
```

Нет, ну можно конечно нагородить другую конструкцию в более традиционном не в ООП стиле:

```
class HumanHero {
   private boolean canFly=false;
   public void fly() {
       if(canFly)
         System.out.println("Flying is awesome!");
       else
         System.out.println("No, I can't fly");
   }

   public void setCanFly(boolean canFly) {
      this.canFly=canFly;
   }
}
```

Фактически это означает, что Зевс должен заранее при проектировании понимать, какие методы и свойства могут иметь его герои.

Нет, ну можно конечно придумывать разные хаки, например можно генерировать исходники компилировать их на лету через [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) загружая через `ClassLoader` или сделать некий метод, к которому цеплять в зависимости от пожеланий Зевса некие парсируемые инструкции и т.д.  - но это все хаки.

Comment: Я прошу прощения за путаницу. Экземпляр класса получает доступ к методам  и параметрам класса используя оператор точка, правильно? Самый главный ответ я получил, то что нужно **заранее при проектировании понимать, какие методы и свойства могут иметь его герои.**. Спасибо!

Comment: Точка это не оператор, а элемент синтаксиса языка - нотация

Comment: В русском переводе Head First Java, обозначен как оператор доступа точка. :)  Я вас понял. Спасибо!    Upd. А в английском варианте звучит так : "You use the dot operator (.) 
on a reference variable to say, 

“use the thing before the dot to 
get me the thing after the dot.”"

Comment: От того, что там написано, точка не становится оператором :) Список операторов Java точно известен и описан в [спецификации языка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12)

Comment: Да, я Вас уже понял. И не стараюсь Вас переубедить. Я только указал, что в этой книге используется этот термин. И в переводе и в оригинале. И в англоязычном сегменте Stackoverflow есть подобные вопросы и ответы. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646364/java-dot-operator-what-it-actually-does. Соответственно, есть пласт многоязычной литературы (или одна книга), где используется неправильная терминология.    Я для себя сделал вывод и более точку в разряд операторов относить не буду.

Answer (score 2):

Экземпляры и методы класса хранятся в различных областях памяти. Экземпляры хранятся в "куче" и содержат только данные для каждого экземпляра отдельно, тогда как методы связаны с классом, хранятся в "Method Area" один раз.

Создавая новый экземпляр вы получаете в куче новое место под данные, но не новый список методов в "Method Area".

По этой причине добавить метод непосредственно экземпляру нельзя. Инструкция, содержащая ссылку на новый метод все равно должна обращаться к "Method Area". А чтобы положить туда этот метод придется создать или модифицировать какой то класс.

Comment: Иными словами, если я хочу чтобы в классе, даже гипотетически, выполнялись какие-то методы, я должен прописать их в процессе создания класса?

Comment: В общем да. Технически можно воткнуть в класс как нибудь поверхностно реализованный метод типа `public void doSomething(){}` и переопределять его для нужного экземпляра. Но компилятор все равно создаст при этом новый анонимный класс, унаследованный от исходного. Это будет почти незаметно, но тем не менее.

Answer (score 1):

В Java это невозможно. Но это есть в JavaScript и это называется прототипным программированием.